# UIView TransitionFromView example?

Tags: iphone, uiview, transition

I would like to use UIView's transitionFromView method to animate a view and catch the event when it is completed. Could some post an example?

Thank you!

F.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
-(IBAction) anAction:(id) sender {
    // assume view1 and view2 are some subviews of self.view
    // view1 will be replaced with view2 in the view hierarchy
    [UIView transitionFromView:view1 
                        toView:view2 
                      duration:0.5 
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft   
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        /* do something on animation completion */
                      }];
    }

}
```

Comment: How can I call a method in ^{ /* Do smth */ } ? Thank you for your help! F.

Comment: This code (called a block) is automatically invoked by the runtime, when the animation finishes.

Comment: Works like a charm! I forgot to write (BOOL finished) before curly braces previously. Thank you! F.

Comment: You know if it is possible to repeat these animation with the options UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse and UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat.